# Backend API login with POST request using LDAP

Tags: spring, api, http, security

Using Spring Security we want to do a POST request to our backend using HTTP. For the authentication we are using LDAP.

Our LDAP connection is working.

Our problem is that we don't really know how to do this (the POST request to our backend). We tried to extend "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' but we already got stuck there. The connection with LDAP now works using a formLogin in the

```
configure(HttpSecurity http)
```

method

We'd also rather NOT use the formLogin, we prefer a simple HTTP POST request

Can anybody give us some pointers?